# Express/Socket.io browser game deployed on Heroku doesn't work as expected

Tags: express, heroku, deployment, socket.io, html5-canvas

I have been working on a hobby browser game project. I use Express and Socket.io to add real-time feature to the game. My game is currently working 60FPS, it updates player's browser window every 16.67 milliseconds. Each frame, client's current position and it's pressed keys data sent to server via socket.io and each frame client receives other users' positions and pressed keys etc. I think that's pretty much of work for free service on Heroku.

You can check my project and problem using this link: https://test-game9.herokuapp.com/

**Problem:** Currently clients are able to move around using W, A, S, D keys. And they can see other user's movements. Nothing else. But for some reason my game deployed on Heroku flickers. This flickering problem doesn't occur on localhost. I wonder what's the problem. Do I miss some kind of socket.io options?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say what is wrong with this game without reviewing the code. However my guess is that you are not considering the network latency that's why your game works in localhost but not when deployed.

When I move using WASD, my object instantly moves. Which indicates that you are directly taking player's action into effect and update object's position then send the position to others. However the preferred alternative is that when player press any movement key, The information about the movement must be sent to the server first then broadcast it to everyone including moved player itself. Even though it's the player's object, player must listen for network to change position instead of doing it locally and instantly like single player games.

Another possible problem is that you are probably using an interval to send player's object position every N milliseconds whether anyone moved or not, This might be another cause of flicker. Instead you can just send position only when someone moves.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess that's the problem and your answer gives me an insight how to solve the problem. As you have mentioned, I update everything client does on browser and then I emit the action to the server. Can you check my code, please? https://github.com/n3pixowe/game. I also want to know how can I implement your suggestion.

Comment: @M.ÇağlarTUFAN I wish I could help you on this but syncing players' state in a game is a complex problem even if the game is simple. I suggest to start with less dynamic games (like  chess or XO) which are turned base and easier to figure out then when you get comfortable then start to move to more real-time games.

Comment: I see, thanks for your answers. I will keep your suggestion on mind. Have a good day!

Comment: hey there! I solved the problem by changing every action to server side and handling player movements with respect to server time and elapsed time of last render time of player. Now it all works really well. I really want to say thank you! If you were not suggested me to do so, I would spend more time on that. You can check it now: https://test-game9.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Glad I could help! I tried it I think you were also in the game. Greatly improved! keep going

Comment: Yes, it was me. I've been moving around the black canvas for like 15 minutes and thinking what should I do with these moving squares. Have a good day, sir!